Video Players doesn't work
I recently installed Ubuntu for learn about how GNU/Linux works.
I have noticed that Ubuntu does not have a built-in video player so I tried to use another one like VLC or Dragon Player but none of them seem to run when opening a video file. So I'm wondering why and how can i fix it.
Thanks for answers

Providing some specifics may help, eg. what Ubuntu product/release are you using? How did you install vlc or dragonplayer as how installed can influence what is pre-setup on your system.  Also giving clues as to what video files & how you're starting them may help us understand & provide help with your issue.

sudo apt-get install ffmpeg will solve everything.

I installed ubuntu 24 LTS. I found VLC on the software store of Ubuntu. I tried to open files like mp4, i also tried to open vlc or dragon and after of that open the video file once the program is running but they just dont work.

This question is similar to: How to install the MPEG-4 AAC decoder and the H.264 decoder?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
